# Backgroundcolor MACD in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I created an MACD on Pine Script version 5. The Backgroundcolor above 0 should be green and below 0 red.
I did this with lines and the fill command. The problem is now that I have to scroll a long time to get the MACD visible, because it is completely compressed when I'm opening a chart. That's caused by the value of the lines at 10000 and -10000.
Is there a possibility to get the highest and lowest value of the MACD of the last 100 bars ?

[That's how it looks like when I'm opening a chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ1io.png)

```
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)

//Linien & Farbe

mitte = hline(0, color=color.new(#787B86, 90), editable=false)
oben = hline(10000, color=color.new(#787B86, 90), editable=false)
unten = hline(-10000, color=color.new(#787B86, 90), editable=false)
fill(oben, mitte, color.new(color.lime, 90), editable=false)
fill(mitte, unten, color.new(color.red, 90), editable=false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The probleme is rather with the `hline()`. It must not be dynamic - according to [definition](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_hline). The price must be an input float/int. So even if you retrieve the highest/lowest for the last 100 bars, you would not be able to apply it dynamically.
How can it still be done?

First, you can use `ta.lowest(macd, 100)` and `ta.highest(macd, 100)` to determine the latest lows/highs of your macd.
Then you'd need to replace `hline()` by eg.:  `line.new(0, ta.highest(macd, 500), time, ta.highest(macd, 500), extend=extend.right, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color=color.new(#787B86, 90))` if you want dynamic results. You can use greater values than 100, like 365 or even 500.
I suggest you add a validation if a new line is needed at all (new higher high/lower low values) and set the line only then and remove the previous one, like:

```
var float macdLowest = 0
var float macdHighest = 0
var line lnLow = na
var line lnHigh = na

mitte = line.new(0, 0, 1, 0, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.right, color=color.new(#787B86, 90))
macdLowestNew = ta.lowest(macd, 500)
macdHighestNew = ta.highest(macd, 500)
if macdLowestNew < macdLowest
    line.delete(lnLow)
    lnLow := line.new(0, macdLowestNew, time, macdLowestNew, extend=extend.right, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color=color.red) // unten
    macdLowest := macdLowestNew
    linefill.new(lnLow, mitte, color.new(#787B86, 90))

if macdHighest < macdHighestNew
    line.delete(lnHigh)
    lnHigh := line.new(0, macdHighestNew, time, macdHighestNew, extend=extend.right, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color=color.green) // oben
    macdHighest := macdHighestNew
    linefill.new(lnHigh, mitte, color.new(#787B86, 90))
...
```

Comment: Sorry for the beginner questions, I'm a newbie..... But now I'm getting the error "The 'timeframe' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects" It's on this line: "mitte = line.new(0, 0, 1, 0, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.right, color=color.new(#787B86, 90))"